# Interpreting regressions with multiple year and month dummy variables

Tags: regression, econometrics, interpretation, regression-coefficients, fixed-effects-model

I have a dependent variable measuring some event, say for each person, I have them in a dataset for a certain amount of months until they die, and they exit the data set. I define my dummy variable = 1 in the month and year in which they die. I want to see if there was a particularly high probability of death in a specific month and year, say july 2007 (maybe a special heat wave happened in that month). **I know a hazard/survival analysis may be most appropriate** for various reasons (censored nature, considering the death conditional on surviving up to this point etc, however I more am using this as an example to understand exactly what a linear regression with dummy variables is measuring. This is also a purely mechanical question for my own understanding, so assume the error is independent of all regressors and so forth, just to focus on the pure interpretation.

So I make a variable called 'treat' which is equal to 1 in july, 2007. I then do the following regression:

$Y_{i,m,y} = \beta Treat + \mu_1Jan + ... + \mu_12 Dec + \psi_1Year2000 + ... + \psi_{10}Year2010 + error$

where the $\mu$'s capture month fixed effects, and the $\psi$\s capture year fixed effects, giving a measure of the probability of death for each month and year, and then my treatment variables aims to see if there is an additional increase in the probability of death for July 2007.

I understand first, due to multicollinearity, at least one of the month dummies must be dropped. say I just drop $\mu_1$ for January.  MY thought process is that I can interpret $\beta$ as measuring if there is any additional increase/decrease in probability for july, 2007, then I would have seen in the absent of any particular event.

However, assuming that is a correct interpretation, I am having trouble directly deriving to confirm that interpretation. For example, I can take:

$E[Y|Treat=1]$, which would then be july ==1 and year2007==1:

$E[y|Treat==1] = \beta Treat + \mu_7July + \psi_7Year2007$

Now normally I would try to do something to isolate $\beta$ to show the interpretation, and I would take:

$E[Y|Treat=0, July ==1, year2007==1] =  \mu_7July + \psi_7Year2007$

, and subtract the two. But I think this latter step is impossible, since if july =1, and 2007=1, necessarily treat must also be one. so deriving the direct interpretation would mean some convoluted expression to get there?

I know the treat dummy is also identifiable, because in a dataset I was able to get an estimate for $\beta$. Say $\beta$ = .012. What exactly does that number tell me? That the heat wave in july was associated with an increased probability of death of 1.2percetnage points beyond what would be expected otherwise in july? if that is correct, then I do not know how I go about showing that?